# Could i use a TFS 2010 with a Asp.net MVC 3 solution created in visual studio 2012

Tags: tfs, visual-studio-2012

I have a tfs2010 server with an old project, and i want to start using VS 2012 for use a better IDE and convert the VS2010 Asp.Net MVC Solution to VS2012 keeping the same framework, could i do this and all stuff of automatic deploy and testing still working on TFS Server?

Comment: Yes you can.  That is my current configuration and have no complaints as of yet.

Answer (score 0):

Sure, VS2012 works well with TFS 2010 and TFS 2010 will hold any code that you send it.  That is, it is agnostic when it comes to the project types that you send to the server.